# Create 2 Dimensional Array in PHP to convert to an JSON array without keys

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I create a 2 dimensional array in php, which I can later convert to a JSON array without keys? The final result is a variable which I like to echo in Java Script should look like this:

```
      [['2012-03-01 05:06:00',37],
            ['2012-03-01 05:07:00',38],
            ['2012-03-01 10:07:00',38],
            ['2012-03-01 10:07:01',39], 
            ['2012-03-01 11:07:01',38],        
            ],
```

I can create an one dimensional array in php with something like this:

```
array_push($date,(string)$r['datTime']);
```

And then convert it to a JSON Array with this:

```
$jsonDate = json_encode($date);
```

But how does this work two or more dimensional?

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: The same way? json_encode doesn't care.

Comment: The output should be a two dimensional JSON array: `[['2012-03-01 05:06:00',37],
            ['2012-03-01 05:07:00',38],
            ['2012-03-01 10:07:00',38],
            ['2012-03-01 10:07:01',39], 
            ['2012-03-01 11:07:01',38]        
            ]`

Comment: Please provide 1) code that we can use to replicate your issue, 2) what the issue is, 3) the expected output.

Comment: But how can I create the 2 Dim PHP Variable without keys for json_encode?

Comment: `$twoDimensions = [ [ 'valuehere', 'another' ], ['even', 'more', 'values' ] ];` is a 2d array without keys.

Comment: Ok, great, is the a method to create these easily, like _array_push_ ?

Comment: @selbolder :- You need output like this? [['2012-03-01 05:06:00',37],['2012-03-01 05:07:00',38],['2012-03-01 10:07:00',38],['2012-03-01 10:07:01',39]]

Comment: Yes, I found the solution for my Problem with your Help Jon: `array_push($Data,array([(string)$r['datTime'],(double)$r['dblTemp']])); `

Comment: there is not enough information. What are the input variables?

Comment: To create a two dimensional array with array_push: `$Data = array();
$TwoDim = array(["Hallo", "Welt"]);
array_push($Data,$TwoDim);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two create a 2 Dimensional array in PHP an to convert it to JSON:

```
    $Data = array();
    $TwoDim = array(["Hallo", "Welt"]);
    array_push($Data,$TwoDim);
    $jsonData = json_encode($Data);
```